# IS there any emoji keyboard available to support custom sticker?

Tags: keyboard

Many emoji keyboard available on the internet.
but any keyboard not support all emoji sticker.
otherwise it isnt possible.
but everyday new emoji sticker coming.
so,any keyboard available to support custom sticker.

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575).

Comment: This isnt off-topic question.It is related on android.

Comment: Please follow the links to find out the truth. There are several topics which are about Android and still off-topic here. To make the links more obvious to you: [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic) explicitly mentions as off-topic: *Questions asking the community to find or recommend something for you (a device, app, ROM, website, etc)*

Comment: Now i understand.but, i need this question answer.

Comment: Then please check the other links as well, there is a place for that: [Where to ask for app recommendations?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575)

Comment: how many stackexchenge site available?like:  (android.stackexchange.com) ,  (meta.stackexchange.com) , 
(stackoverfollow.com) .etc

Comment: Please note this is [not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/192154), so no place for discussion (you can discuss things in our chat rooms once you've reached 20+ rep). As for available SE sites, [see here](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: @nomito: This isn't a *paid* help line to answer all your doubts. You have asked a question, you have been told it's off topic here, you've been directed to a site where you can ask, provided if it fits the rules of the site. That is enough spoon feeding. Please learn to do your own research too

Comment: @izzy: you are really patient :)

Comment: @beeshyams I try my best, but there are limits :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SwiftKey Keyboard - Android Apps on Google Play.

or

Go Keyboard supports emoji sticker but you have to update further sticker for that in keyboard pannel at + sticker click.

Comment: Thank you, for your attempt to help out here, but please avoid  answering off-topic questions. *Answers to such questions tend to encourage users to ask such off-topic content again. Off-topic content diminishes the desired usefulness of a website*. Visit [help/on-topic] to know what's on-topic and off-topic *[inter alia](http://android.stackexchange.com/help)*.e, but